# Pourquoi « laisse-moi » mais « laisse-le » ?

Tags: pronoms, impératif

Pourquoi est-ce « laisse-moi » mais « Laisse-le » ?

Est-ce que dire "laisse-me" est aussi possible ?

Pourquoi est-ce un pronom indirect dans le premier cas mais un pronom direct dans le deuxième ?

Answer (score 6):

A l'impératif, les pronoms des première et deuxième personnes du singulier **me/te** sont remplacés par leurs variantes toniques **moi/toi** quand ils sont placés après le verbe:

> Laisse-moi
>
> Laisse-toi
>
> Laisse-le

À l'impératif négatif, ces pronoms sont placés avant le verbe, **me** et **te** sont donc utilisés:

> Ne me laisse pas
>
> Ne te laisse pas
>
> Ne le laisse pas

On rencontre dans la littérature ces pronoms non accentués et placés avant le verbe dans des tournures positives, par exemple :

> Va, sois en repos, rentre, et **me** laisse faire

*Molière*, L'école des maris.

> Va flatter, si tu veux, la douleur de Flavie, Et **me** laisse éclaircir de l'état de ma vie

*Corneille*, Théodore.

Answer (score 0):

My try at answering this.
I would say first, that it's the third person that does not follow the rule. (1st person is "moi" it could not be "laisse-me" simply because moi is the default form and becomes "me" or "m'" only when put before a verb)
However it's not "Laisse-lui" because the third person is the only one with two forms to mark the difference between accusative/dative or direct and indirect object.
See : « Laisse-moi partir / laisse-moi un message ». Let me go /leave me a message
But : « Laisse-le partir  / Laisse-lui un message »  (laisse-la partir, laisse-lui un message)
« Je fais quoi du pull de mark ? Laisse-le lui. »  Leave it TO him.
So here "Le" is accusative and "lui" is dative.

Why a different set of rules for it? I'd say because of the ambiguity caused in the sentence by the genderisation of objects in french.